# JPA inheritance issue with ObjectDB - Field not found in type error

Tags: jpa, objectdb

I'm using ObjectDB as my JPA provider, and I'm facing an issue with inheritance. My classes are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable, Comparable<Item> {
    boolean retired;
    // other fields, getters, and setters
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
public class PharmaceuticalItem extends Item implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
public class Vtm extends PharmaceuticalItem implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

I have a JPQL query that looks like this:

```
String jpql = "Select vtm "
            + " from Vtm vtm "
            + " where vtm.retired=:ret "
            + " order by vtm.name";
```

When I try to run this query, I get the following error:

```
Error executing query: Field 'retired' is not found in type 'com.divudi.entity.pharmacy.Vtm'
```

The same code works fine with MySQL and EclipseLink, but not with ObjectDB. I've also tried using the @MappedSuperclass annotation instead of the @Inheritance annotation, but the issue persists.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Item implements Serializable, Comparable<Item> {
    // ...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class PharmaceuticalItem extends Item implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Vtm extends PharmaceuticalItem implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue with ObjectDB?

Thanks in advance!

This is the method in abstract facade.

```
public List<T> findByJpql(String temSQL, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    System.out.println("findByJpql");
    System.out.println("JPQL: " + temSQL);
    System.out.println("Parameters: " + parameters);
    
    TypedQuery<T> qry = getEntityManager().createQuery(temSQL, entityClass);
    Set s = parameters.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        String pPara = (String) m.getKey();
        if (m.getValue() instanceof Date) {
            Date pVal = (Date) m.getValue();
            qry.setParameter(pPara, pVal, TemporalType.DATE);
        } else {
            Object pVal = (Object) m.getValue();
            qry.setParameter(pPara, pVal);
        }
    }
    
    List<T> ts;
    try {
        ts = qry.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Results found: " + ts.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error executing query: " + e.getMessage());
        ts = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    return ts;
}
```

This is the method in the controller.

```
public String navigateToListAllVtms() {
    System.out.println("navigateToListAllVtms");
    String jpql = "Select vtm "
            + " from Vtm vtm "
            + " where vtm.retired=:ret "
            + " order by vtm.name";
    System.out.println("JPQL: " + jpql);

    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("ret", false);
    System.out.println("Parameters: " + m);

    items = getFacade().findByJpql(jpql, m);
    
    if (items == null) {
        System.out.println("Items list is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Items list size: " + items.size());
        for (Vtm item : items) {
            System.out.println("Vtm: " + item);
        }
    }

    return "/emr/reports/vtms?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Inheritance) for `@Inheritance`

> Defines the inheritance strategy to be used for an entity class
> hierarchy. **It is specified on the entity class that is the root of the
> entity class hierarchy**. If the Inheritance annotation is not specified
> or if no inheritance type is specified for an entity class hierarchy,
> the SINGLE_TABLE mapping strategy is used.

You annotated your sub-classes with `@Inheritance` which is the opposite of what the doc says. Hence the following changes should work.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance // added
public class Item ...

@Entity
// removed @Inheritance 
public class PharmaceuticalItem extends Item ...

@Entity
// removed @Inheritance 
public class Vtm extends PharmaceuticalItem ...
```

Comment: It resolved the error completely. Now working as a charm.